# UITextView text in Tableview get Overrides?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my app i am customised the UITableView Cell with four UITextViews. Whenever i added data to the tableview and reload it. The text in the UITableViewCell get override with the previous texts.

I tried different approaches but couldn't figure out what was the problem.

I am using TableView in View Controller.

Here is the Code i used in my table View cell?

```
if ( [tableView isEqual:self.tableActions])
{
    //Setting the text empty

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActionsIdentifier";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    NSLog(@"Index Path %i",[indexPath row]);
    ActionDetails *actiondetails = [actionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"Action Text %@",actiondetails.actions);

    //Actions
    actionText=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 230,30)];
    actionText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    actionText.editable = NO;
    actionText.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    actionText.text = actiondetails.actions ; 
    actionText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    actionText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:actionText];


    //Owner         
    ownerBy=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 5, 230,30)];
    ownerBy.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    ownerBy.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    ownerBy.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    ownerBy.text = actiondetails.owner;
    ownerBy.editable = NO;
    ownerBy.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    ownerBy.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ownerBy];

 }
```

ScreenShot
[image]

Thanks for your help guys.

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys +1 for all your supports..

Comment: Do You get the solution for this. I am having the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me a other day, the solution that I came up with was removing all subview from the cell after creating the cell in the if statement.

```
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove cell identifier of Tableview otherwise take Customcell for the Tableview..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry what do you mean remove cell identifier or take customcell for the tableview

Comment: in your code you have taken cellidentifier remove this and set cell identifier to nil..
`cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];`
and in 
`cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];`

Comment: You are reusing cell that's why problem occurs

Comment: another way to do this is andypaul's answer.. see below

Comment: Hi hiren the click event is not workign in tableview when i use nil in cell identifier

Comment: it is not related to cell identifier

Comment: I hope so but when i use cell identifier its working perfectly fine. but when i set to nil it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Just simple try this way :

```
 {
        //Setting the text empty

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActionsIdentifier";

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        **// if(cell == nil) // comment this line in your code ,its work 
       // {**
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
       **// }**
        NSLog(@"Index Path %i",[indexPath row]);
        ActionDetails *actiondetails = [actionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSLog(@"Action Text %@",actiondetails.actions);

        //Actions
        actionText=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 230,30)];
        actionText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        actionText.editable = NO;
        actionText.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        actionText.text = actiondetails.actions ; 
        actionText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        actionText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:actionText];


        //Owner         
        ownerBy=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 5, 230,30)];
        ownerBy.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        ownerBy.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        ownerBy.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        ownerBy.text = actiondetails.owner;
        ownerBy.editable = NO;
        ownerBy.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        ownerBy.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ownerBy];

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the cell.  Reused cell  already has UITextview added to it.So you are overriding on it. 
You must shift all your code of creating and adding UITextView to.

> If(cell==nil)
>     {
>
> }

After which you only need to set the Text to UITextview.

Answer (score 0):

when your view did appear write reload your table view.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
[tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

           // your code 

        }

          // your code 

        return cell;    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id vw in [[cell contentView] subviews]) {
    if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
       UILabel *label = (UILabel *)vw;
       [label removeFromSuperview];
    }
 }

 for (id vw in [cell subviews]) {
     if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
     {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)vw;
        [label removeFromSuperview];
     }
 }
```